# Carrier generation at receiver in DSB-SC modulation?

Tags: signal, frequency, modulation, demodulation

[image]

As shown in fig., In this scheme input signal is square and passed through a narrow(high Q) bandpass filter **tuned to \$ w_c\$**.Finally the ouput comes to be a sinusoid of frequency  \$ w_c\$.

But to implement this scheme you need prior information of \$ w_c\$ because you need to tuned your bandpass filter at \$ w_c\$.

My question is that if you know \$ w_c\$ then why not just use a crystal oscillator to generate carrier of same. why use all PLL, filters etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a coherent detector and not any old arbitrary oscillator module or crystal that is stamped with the correct frequency. It has to be phase coherent i.e. exactly the same frequency and a stable (relatively) phase. This is why squaring or Costas loops are used. Costas loop: -

[image]

Without the continuous presence of a carrier (i.e. the carrier is suppressed) you have to use these methods.

The band-pass filter used in a squaring coherent carrier detection system does need to be broadly centred at the carrier frequency but it must have a pass-band that is wide enough so that errors are not significant.

A filter does not make a local oscillator signal phase coherent - the act of squaring the signal and then removing DC and double frequency components gives you phase coherence. The PLL is superfluous to a squaring coherent detector BTW.

Comment: But in costa's receiver quiescent frequency of the oscillator is same as carrier in modulated signal y(t). Let's say y(t) can have any frequency between ( 90 -107 MHz ). Is it required to change quiescent frequency of the oscillator whenever \$ w_c\$ changes.

Comment: A costas loop works after the IF stage when the input frequency covers a significant range. See this: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hqkKAV1KsrQC&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=costas+loop+in+a+receiver&source=bl&ots=3R787esyAN&sig=qJnYiGnynUFwUAgDXr0yiLLNnqE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBGoVChMIsLLsl6qXyQIVQf4OCh2iRQdk#v=onepage&q=costas%20loop%20in%20a%20receiver&f=false this indeed means that the the VCO has to shift in order to detect a different carrier range. Ditto the low pass and high pass filters.

Comment: The same is true of the BPF in a squaring loop.